# dimension error using IF loop

Tags: r, if-statement

I ran the following code:

```
c<-matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,0),byrow=6)
aa<-NULL
bin_revenue<-function(x) {
for (i in 1:length(x))
aa<-if (x[i,]==0) {x[i,]=0
} else {
x[i,]=1
}
aa
}

bin_revenue(c)
```

When I ran this code, I got the following error:

```
Error in x[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions.
```

All I am trying to do is get a binary matrix.

Please help. I know there are other methods but I specifically need to know what I did wrong. I am trying to learn how to write loops so please don't give me alternate solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `c(0,1,4,2,0)` is not a matrix but a vector (and hence *one*-dimensional).

Comment: `c<-matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,0),bycol=6)` does not work. Do you want `c <- matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,0), ncol = 6)`?

Comment: sorry it should be byrow=6

Comment: and assuming it's a data-frame with heading 'c'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `aa` as a numeric vector, not `NULL`.

```
> c <- matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,0),byrow=6)
> aa <- numeric()
> bin_revenue <- function(x) {
      for (i in 1:length(x)){
          aa[i] <- ifelse(x[i] == 0, 0, 1)
      }
    aa
  }

> bin_revenue(c)
## [1] 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for:

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,0), byrow = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(c = mat)

bin_revenue <- function(x) 
  as.data.frame("[<-"(as.matrix(x), , as.integer(as.logical(as.matrix(x)))))

bin_revenue(dat)
#   c
# 1 0
# 2 1
# 3 1
# 4 1
# 5 1
# 6 0
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize while writing that. Please read the code again

Comment: Thanks. But what did I do wrong? Like why is there a dimension mistake?